# Unit Tests fail when run together, pass individually

Tags: c#, unit-testing

So I am having a few issues with my unit Tests, I cant just copy and past them here but I will give what I can.

The problem seems to be that if I run the tests one by one everything works as intended, but if I tell it to run the tests all together 1/5 will pass,

```
[TestMethod]

    public void ObjTest()
    {
        //Arrange - multiple ecus and items 
        var t = new var();
        t.itemNumbers = new List<ItemNumber>();

        obj e = new obj();
        e.property = "(12345 OR 55555) AND !65232";

        Globals.masterList.Add(e);

        ItemNumber i = new ItemNumber();
        i.num= "12345";

        ItemNumber i1 = new ItemNumber();
        i1.num= "55555";

        ItemNumber i2 = new ItemNumber();
        i2.num= "55556";
        t.itemNumbers.Add(i);
        t.itemNumbers.Add(i1); 
        t.itemNumbers.Add(i2);

        ICollection<Iinterface> tmp = new List<Iinterface>();

        //act, process the ecu and item lists
        ;
        functionCalled(t.itemNumbers, Globals.masterList, ref tmp);

        //assert, there should be only 2 added to the list
        Assert.AreEqual(1, tmp.Count, " ");
        Assert.AreEqual("(12345 OR 55555) AND !65232", functionCalled(t.itemNumbers, Globals.masterList, ref tmp), "Wrong obj returned.");

    }
```

All of the unit tests are basically a copy and past with the chages to e.property and possibly a change to one of the i numbers,

the tests are designed to check edge cases cased by user input.

is there something I am missing to ensure scope clears all of the variables and everything between tests. or force serial execution.

Comment: My guess is that `Globals.masterList.Add(e);` is your problem - having a global element to your tests means that they're not separate from each other. It smells bad.

Comment: I will suck my pinkytoe if it hasn't got something to do with `Globals.masterList.Add(e)`.

Comment: as @dav_i suggests you are probably hit by a static member being shared between your lists. i, i1 and i2 are then added by the threads and your assertions about their presence becomes unreliable.

Comment: I'd also *strongly* recommend against naming a type `var`. That's just *designed* to confuse people...

Comment: Not an issue but -var t = new var();- ...

Comment: Do you have to use `Globals.masterList`? Can you mock it out instead so you can isolate it in each test?

Comment: @JonSkeet var is not what it actually is, changed to hide class naming

Comment: and it was the global ! I cant believe i didn't see that....

Comment: If you're going to use "dummy" names, I'd suggest avoiding ones which are contextual keywords then.

Comment: @JonSkeet I will keep that in mind next time I post to StackOverflow

Answer (score 1):

I propose to consider `Globals.masterList.Add(e);` 
Let's say your unit test executed in five threads. It means that `Globals.masterList.Add(e);` will be executed five times or masterList will be modified by five different threads. 
Then you have next line of code:

```
Assert.AreEqual("(12345 OR 55555) AND !65232", functionCalled(t.itemNumbers, Globals.masterList, ref tmp), "Wrong obj returned.");
```

functionCalled deals with modified list by other functions, and as outcome you have different output from it and as result failed unit test