# Unit Tests Fail when "Run All" in Visual Studio but passes individually

Tags: c#, unit-testing, visual-studio-2012, moq

I am having this wierd problem with MOQ Unit tests.

I have around 636 unit tests written using MOQ Framework in VS 2012.
When I run them project-wise and/or individually, they pass successfully. but whenever I select Run-All they fail randomly showing different errors.

Most of the methods show IO.FileNotFoundException.

I looked [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8987231/my-test-fail-when-run-together-but-pass-individually) [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28093133/unit-tests-fail-when-run-together-pass-individually) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1479803/c-sharp-could-not-load-file-or-assembly-system-cannot-find-file-specified) but no clue yet.

**Edited**:

I solved the problem of FileNotFoundException using **DeploymentItem**[] attribute.

But still one of the project is failing when RunAll. exception tells - "**Cannot convert, incompatible types**" on of the properties.

Comment: Do you have anything in the config files of individual test projects that the failing tests need? When you run all tests in a solution it isn't able to pick these up per project.

Comment: Are you using ReSharper? I have had a similar problem to this while running all with ReSharper.

Comment: Could you provide more detail on the exceptions you're getting? Do you know which file can't be found? Also, are your tests being run synchronously or asynchronously?

Comment: Do your tests do any set up and tear down of resources? If you have multiple tests accessing the same file it could cause issues especially if any of them change it. It might be an idea to post the code of one of the tests which occasionally fails.

Comment: I solved the problem for FileNotFoundException. I used DeploymentItem["NeededProject.dll"]. it worked

Answer (score 0, accepted):

seems like I missed using DeploymentItem["NeededProject.dll"] for each unit test class.
Its working fine now. :)